# jQuery .html() not setting html at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple thing. When a user clicks on the `edit` link it turns the previous element into an `input` element for editing and the `edit` into a `cancel`. If the user decides not to edit he can click on `cancel` and everything should revert to its initial state.

Right now this is not working at all:

```
$('.cancel').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().html("<a href='#'>edit</a>");
});
```

HTML:

```
        <div class='photo-section'>

            <div class='photo-head'>
                <div class='photo-info'>
                    Photo Name : <span class='photo-name'>Work selfie</span>
                    <span class='title-edit'><a href='#'>edit</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='photo'>
                <img src='' alt='' title=''>
            </div>

            <div class='tag-section'>
                <div class='tags'>Photo Tags:
                    <span>#code#coffee#late#night</span>
                    <span class="tags-edit"><a href="#" class="">edit</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
// JavaScript to handle photo operations

$(document).ready(function() {

    // show/hide edit option
    $('.photo-info, .tags').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.title-edit > a, .tags-edit > a').addClass('visible');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.title-edit > a, .tags-edit > a').removeClass('visible');
    });

    // show editable area
    $('.title-edit, .tags-edit').on('click', function () {
        edit(this);
    });

});

function edit(elem) {
    // change element into an input elemnt for editing
    var $item = $(elem).prev();
    var text = $item.text();
    $item.html("<input type='text'>").find('input').attr('value', text);

    // change edit to cancel if input element present
    if ($('input').length) {
        $item.next().html("<a href='#' class='cancel'>cancel</a>");
    }

    // change cancel back to edit
    if ($('.cancel').length) {

        $('.cancel').on('click', function() {
            $(this).parent().html("<a href='#'>edit</a>");
        });
    }
}
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/hgwkxygz/6/
Any help would be great!

Comment: Since your question is not about PHP, you should replace the PHP code with its HTML output.

Comment: It does work, but the earlier click handler triggers right after and it goes back to a cancel link.

Comment: In demo you are looking for `prev()` of element that has no previous sibling. Really not clear what this code should be doing. Use raw html to troubleshoot client side...not php. We shouldn't have to parse your server code for you

Comment: Ok I updated the code and omitted the php.

Comment: AS well as the jsfiddle

Comment: You should look into using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Then you can define the event handlers for the buttons before they even exist. Also, use the pattern `$(this).closest('.container').find('.item')` rather than `.prev()` and the like. It makes for less brittle code. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hgwkxygz/7/)

Comment: Thanks @John! If you put that in an answer i will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common case of attaching event at wrong time in javascript.
Actually you are removing and re-adding a DOM element. So the already attached event to .cancel won't work this time. You again have to write event listener on .cancel whenever you attach a new DOM element after clicking on edit button.

Basically it means whenever you do .html(), you have to re-add event listener for click.

There are various approach to solve this problem.

1) make a function which attach the DOM element as well as click event to that DOM element. Call that function only on click events.

2)Do event delegation.

3)Do not remove DOM elements on click events, rather hide and show elements so that you wont loose your event listeners.

4)If you really have to do remove and re-add DOM elements then in my opinion, best approach is to make a class, where you make DOM elements, add event listeners privately in that class, and on click events just make new instance of that class.

You can check out these options in detail on web.